# Determine if JSON parsing was successful in python

Tags: python, json

What kind of exceptions can I expect to be thrown if I try to parse invalid JSON with `json.load`? I couldn't find this in the documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not try it ;)

```
>>> json.loads('ewrwerw')
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Grepping for `raise` in the sourcecode of the `json` module will also show that nothing but `ValueError` is raised.

---

In case you use `simplejson`:

```
class JSONDecodeError(ValueError):
```

So catching `ValueError` will also work with `simplejson`.

Comment: I've tried it and gotten that error. But I'm curious if there are any others I might expect to catch.

Comment: Nope, only this one unless you pass something not a string (that would give you `TypeError`)